# Is there a list of punctuations removed in standard analyzer in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the [official documentation of the standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html#analysis-analyzers) in Elasticsearch, it is mentioned that "It removes most punctuation".

I need the list of the punctuations that this standard analyzer removes. Can someone point me to any reference or section of the Elasticsearch source code that might be useful in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic search standard Analyzer based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in Unicode Standard Annex [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/). There are couple of rules and regex that you can find in the documentation in detail.